# SQL Server - Simultaneous Outcomes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and still learning.

I am stuck with a question in which it says list if there is any model that was in the top 5 in terms of quantity, simultaneously in 2008, 2009 and 2010.

[image: Please find the table Schema Here]

Table schema

Should I use `Case` statement or anything else to arrive at the result? Actually it is just a query question and my teacher asked me to assume the data so I am sorry I won't be able to provide the table. Any other way to do the same. Because Case Statement is fine but I love alternate ways too to solve the queries. Please let me know if there is some other way too to solve the query

Comment: if you ask should i use case statement then answer should be yes, but does it be solved your problem? you have to share data and what you tried so far and where you got problem then any one can help you

Comment: case statement will do the job, I would also recommend checking exists function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Cool . Anyother way to do the same. Because Case Statement is fine but I love alternate ways too to solve the queries. Please let me know if there is some other way too to solve the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is similar to the one from Michal Turczyn, but it respects the fact that there can by more than one transaction per year and model, also it allows for ties:

```
WITH
  Ranking (IdModel, rn) AS (
    SELECT IdModel,
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Date) ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC)
    FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS
    WHERE YEAR(Date) IN (2008, 2009, 2010)
    GROUP BY YEAR(Date), IdModel
  )
SELECT IdModel
FROM Ranking
WHERE rn <= 5
GROUP BY IdModel
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Short and Simple Thanks @Wolfgang Kais !

Answer (score 1):

Below query will give you ranking of `Model` in terms of `Quantity` in years 2008, 2009 and 2010
(`ROW_NUMBER` will give you ranking position of `Model`):

```
SELECT IdModel,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR([Date]) ORDER BY Quantity DESC) rn
FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE YEAR([Date]) IN (2008, 2009, 2010)
```

Then, to get final result, you have to wrap it in another query, filter by `rn` to get top 5
(`WHERE rn <= 5`) and `GROUP BY` with `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` to see if any `Model` was present
three times in a resultset (meaning it was in top five in those three years):

```
SELECT IdModel FROM (
    SELECT IdModel,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR([Date]) ORDER BY Quantity DESC) rn
    FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS
    WHERE YEAR([Date]) IN (2008, 2009, 2010)
) a
WHERE rn <= 5
GROUP BY IdModel
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Great idea, but there won't be just one transaction per year and model. In your inner query, you have to group by `Year` and `IdModel`. Then, in the `OVER` clause, `ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC)`.

Comment: @WolfgangKais Well, you are right, if you assume it, but my assumption was slightly different. For beginner, query including your regards would become far to more complicated and I aimed at simplicity :)

Comment: Thank you @Michal !

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want to count the number of transactions for each model.  To aggregate and rank:

```
select t.idmodel, year(date) as yyyy, count(*) as cnt,
       rank() over (partition by year(date) order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
from transactions t
group by idmodel, year(date);
```

Note that this uses `rank()` rather than `row_number()`; this handles ties for fifth place Now to get the top 5 for each year we use a subquery:

```
select idmodel, yyyy
from (select t.idmodel, year(date) as yyyy, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by year(date) order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from transactions t
      group by idmodel, year(date) 
     ) m
where seqnum <= 5;
```

Now to get models for all three years, we can do filtering and counting:

```
select idmodel
from (select t.idmodel, year(date) as yyyy, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by year(date) order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from transactions t
      group by idmodel, year(date) 
     ) m
where seqnum <= 5 and yyyy in (2008, 2009, 2010)
group by idmodel
having count(*) = 3;
```

There are other methods.  For instance, `in` or `exists`:

```
with modelyearrank as (
      select t.idmodel, year(date) as yyyy, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by year(date) order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from transactions t
      group by idmodel, year(model)
     )
select m.*
from dim_model m
where exists (select 1
              from modelyearrank
              where myr.idmodel = m.idmodel and yyyy = 2008 and seqnum <= 5
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from modelyearrank
              where myr.idmodel = m.idmodel and yyyy = 2009 and seqnum <= 5
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from modelyearrank
              where myr.idmodel = m.idmodel and yyyy = 2010 and seqnum <= 5
             );
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon. This is very well explained and it works. Though I had to struggle a bit to understand as I am new but it's great thanks !

Comment: @BeyonDIN . . . Is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?  As the OP, you can accept any answer you like, but I can ask.

Comment: I tried all the answers and they work great. I am thankful to all for teaching me so many alternate ways. The only reason I chose wolfgang's answer because it is very short and I think very simple to understand for newbie's like me. But your methods are awesome. I understood what you taught me ! It just has many concepts at once. Thank you for your time @Gordon!

Comment: @BeyonDIN . . . I didn't notice that Wolfgang submitted his answer before mine, which is a very reasonable reason to accept that version (I might still like my answer better, but that is in the realm of my personal opinion).